# SQL query to return only items with a value >0

Tags: sql

First let me explain that I don't use SQL very much.

I'm using someone else's code and need to reduce the number of lines returned by discounting anything with a zero in the `WHERE` clause.
However I'm not sure how to do this as the items I want to discount are the result of a calulation = 'openquantity'

```
SELECT
    stockallocations.partid,
    stockallocations.quantity - issuedquantity as openquantity,
    (CASE   
        WHEN stockallocations.source = 'SO' THEN stockallocations.reference
        WHEN stockallocations.source = 'KIT' THEN stockallocations.worksorderid
        ELSE 'Manual'
    END) as source,
    (CASE   
        WHEN stockallocations.source = 'SO' THEN salesorderitems.duedate
        WHEN stockallocations.source = 'KIT' THEN worksorders.lateststartdate
        ELSE 'createddate'
    END) as needed
FROM
    stockallocations
    LEFT OUTER JOIN salesorderitems ON
    stockallocations.orderid = salesorderitems.orderid AND
    stockallocations.orderitemnumber = salesorderitems.itemnumber
    LEFT OUTER JOIN worksorders ON
    stockallocations.worksorderid = worksorders.id

WHERE
    stockallocations.partid = 'ABC123'
    --and openquantity > 0 (this doesn't work).
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your code uses non-standard syntax). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using postgresql, oracle, sql-server, db2, ...

Comment: If this is SQL server you cannot use column aliases in a where clause so you would have to do `where (stockallocations.quantity - issuedquantity) > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use `and (stockallocations.quantity - issuedquantity) > 0` instead of `and openquantity > 0`. Aliases will not work in `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure SQL allows you to use Aliases in WHERE clauses.

Try this instead:

```
WHERE
    stockallocations.partid = 'ABC123'
AND stockallocations.quantity - issuedquantity > 0
```

Thanks,
Dom

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use alias in the `WHERE` clause. Instead, use either

```
SELECT * from (SELECT ...) WHERE openquantity > 0
```

or

```
WITH SEL1 as (SELECT ...)
SELECT * from SEL1 where openquantity > 0
```

or if the computation is that simple as here, just copy it:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE stockallocations.partid = 'ABC123'
AND stockallocations.quantity - issuedquantity > 0
```

Note that the first two options might not work on every database.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would write your query using table aliases and fix the column alias problem in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT sa.partid, (sa.quantity - issuedquantity) as openquantity,
       (CASE WHEN sa.source = 'SO' THEN sa.reference
             WHEN sa.source = 'KIT' THEN sa.worksorderid
             ELSE 'Manual'
        END) as source,
       (CASE  WHEN sa.source = 'SO' THEN soi.duedate
              WHEN sa.source = 'KIT' THEN wo.lateststartdate
             ELSE 'createddate'
        END) as needed
FROM stockallocations sa LEFT JOIN
     salesorderitems soi ON
     ON sa.orderid = soi.orderid AND
        sa.orderitemnumber = soi.itemnumber LEFT JOIN
     worksorders wo ON
     ON sa.worksorderid = wo.id
WHERE sa.partid = 'ABC123' AND
      sa.quantity > issuedquantity;
```

Next, presumably `issuedquantity` is from `stockallocations`.  If not, the `WHERE` clause is turning one or more `LEFT JOIN`s into `INNER JOIN`s.

And finally, the `CASE` expressions are suspicious.  The `ELSE` clauses return strings, but `sa.worksorderid` might be numeric and the dates look like dates.  When you mix types like this in a single expression, you will often get type conversion errors.